# How to get “failed login attempts since the last successful login” count as a variable?

Tags: linux, security, logging

When I log in to a server I see:

```
Last failed login: Fri Jul 17 12:47:01 CEST 2020 from 111.222.333.444 on ssh:notty
There were 2713 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
Last login: Fri Jul 17 01:12:57 2020 from ec2-111-222-333-444.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

How do I get number 2713 after the login using some command, without parsing auth logs manually?

The OS is CentOS 7 if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var=`cat file | grep "There were" | cut -d' ' -f3`
```

Another way to do this:

```
var=`cat /var/log/secure | grep "Failed password" | wc -l`
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I get this SSH login output to the variable itself?
Or it is stored somewhere in a file?

Comment: See the another way in the edit

Comment: This approach will count all failed logins, not since the last successful login. It is possible to find the last successful login in logs and count only from there.
But the main point - it should be some command or variable to show this number, without manual parsing logs.